# SSRS Multiplication doesnt work right for some values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Im trying to do a multiplication between to fields, but for some reason it doesnt bring the right amount. Here the columns

[image]

and the expression im using

```
=ROUND(Fields!ValueEntrySalesInvoiceLineQuantity.Value * Fields!Netweight.Value)
```

which bring these results. As you can see, some like 5*6 brings 28 instead 30. Could somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the Quantity is whole numbers? The ROUND wouldn't be necessary if it is. Can you change the Format to `N2` in the properties to show some places to verify? I hadn't heard of multiplication issues.

Comment: In additional to Hannover's suggestion, remove all formatting on the fields, remove the rounding on the calc and start from there. My suspicion is that your `5` is actually something like `4.7` and being formatted to 0 decimals. `6*4.7 = 28.2` which rounded to zero decimals will show as `28`